# Реализация прохождения сквозь стены в игре змейка на JS (Snake)

Tags: javascript, canvas

Попробовал добавить возможность змее проходить сквозь стены.
Возникло несколько проблем.

- Змейя при  прохождении сквозь стену теряет по одной части тела, Пока
  не исчезнет.
- Еда становить не активной.
- Если длина змеи меньше 2 сквозь стены она проходит но не
  возвращаеться с другой стороны.

Решения вероятно совсем кривоея, так как иногда совсем ничего не срабатывает.
Укажите пожалуйста на ошибки, буду благодарен за пример как нужно было б.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`throughWall()` нужно вызывать после того, как координаты змеи уже перестроены.

К вашему фидлу нет доступа. HTML и CSS для примера взял из вопроса об ускорении.

Пример: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/25ju0yxa/).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Ваши ответы помогли.  Не заметил что к фидлу нет доступа. (